# Laravel jobs leaves an idle postgresql process on DEALLOCATE

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-5.4, supervisord, laravel-queue

Every time a Delayed Job is has run on my server I can see a new idle process in postgreSQL. Running `select * from pg_stat_activity;` I can see:

```
DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000018
```

I tried to understand, and one more line (and one more process in `htop`) appears each time a delayed queued job had just ran.

The last line of my Job is:

```
$this->log->info("Invitation {$this->invitation->uuid} sent");
```

And I can see this in my logs, so everything is alright BUT it does not clean up after. I have a idle process every time with "DEALLOCATE pdo_stmt_00000xxx".

What can I do to avoid this problem? What is causing this?

Here is my supervisor config:

```
[program:laravel-queue-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /path/to/my/site/artisan queue:work --queue=invitation,default --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/to/my/logs/worker.log
```

*Side note: the idle processes disappear when I run `php artisan queue:restart`*

Comment: it seems to deallocate prepared statement to be able reuse that name pdo_stmt_00000xxx, and does not end connection? maybe it is meant to run over pgbouncer with user pool mode set to transaction?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a (quick and dirty) workaround. Adding this at the end of my Job handle function:

```
\DB::disconnect();
sleep(1);
```

A issue has been opened on Laravel: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18384